# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin.model' doesn't exist

Tags: php, database, laravel, model

How to fix this error. I am trying to update data in table. 
This is my controller

```
 public function update($id)
    {
        $input = request()->all();

        return response()->json(['success' => true], 200);
    }
```

This is my model

```
namespace App\Models\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ModelsCategory extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'models_categories';

    protected $guarded  = ['id'];

}
```

Comment: This is not the code giving the error. Your first bit does not request any models, and the second does not refer to `admin.model` at all.

Comment: I agree. There's definitely more going on and you didn't post the relevant code here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have not made any updates within the function

Make changes like me

```
public function update(Requeat $request, $id)
{

    ModelsCategory::where("id",$id)->update([
      // Herer set your column and data like this
          'tiltle'=>$request->title,
    ]);

    return response()->json(['success' => true], 200);
}
```

Or you can use this.

first change route like this:

```
 Route::post("/category/{modelscategory}","categorycontroller@update")
```

update mthod

```
public function update(Requeat $request, ModelsCategory $modelscategory)
{
    $modelscategory->title=$request->title;

    $modelscategory->save();
    return response()->json(['success' => true], 200);
}
```

I hope I helped

Comment: Your code changes don't look related at all with the original issue (a table not found in the database).